# Macro stops working correctly in last quarter

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm new to the forum and will try to make my question as clear as possible. I use a Macro to help organize monthly financial information into a General Journal. Essentially this Macro takes info from other worksheets and organizes/rearranges it into a separate worksheet - the General Journal. It always adds info to the bottom of my list while ignoring all previous info on my list. Now, all year long my Macro functions perfectly until the last quarter of the year. For some reason it gets confused by the dates and selects the wrong date range to organize on my General Journal. Where it should be selecting only information from October, it is selecting all info from February through October. The code is EXACTLY the same from the previous months. If I were to change my dates from October to September, the Macro functions perfectly again and only selects and manipulates my September info - great! But why does it get confused in October-December?? The ONLY difference in my code is which date range to select. I've made sure my cells are correctly formatted for dates and not text so this is very confusing. Any help would be appreciated! I've pasted the section of my code that is giving me trouble. The code references dates in column "B" then selects the corresponding cells with info in column "F"

```
Sub L()
'Selects Credits and shifts down one cell
Dim nRow9   As Long
Dim nstart9 As Long, nEnd9 As Long
'figure out where date data starts
For nRow9 = 4 To 65536
    If Range("B" & nRow9).Value >= "10/1/2017" Then
        nstart9 = nRow9
        Exit For
    End If
Next nRow9
'figure out where date data ends
For nRow9 = nstart9 To 65536
    If Range("B" & nRow9).Value = "10/31/2017" Then
        nEnd9 = nRow9
        Exit For
    End If
Next nRow9
Range("F" & nstart9 & ":F" & nEnd9).Select
'Dim r9 As Range
'Set r9 = Selection
'Intersect(r9(1).EntireRow, r9).Insert Shift:=xlDown, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Comment: You are treating your dates as strings, and (for instance) `"10/22/2017"` comes before `"2/10/2017"` in an alphanumeric sequence.  Or, in your case, `"2/1/2017"` comes after `"10/1/2017"`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1):

I forced a conversion to `Date` for both of the cells being evaluated (`CDate()`)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateGeneralJournal()
    'Selects Credits and shifts down one cell
    Dim nRow9   As Long
    Dim nstart9 As Long, nEnd9 As Long

    'figure out where date data starts
    For nRow9 = 4 To 65536
        If CDate(Range("B" & nRow9).Value) >= CDate("10/1/2017") Then
            nstart9 = nRow9
            Exit For
        End If
    Next nRow9

    'figure out where date data ends
    For nRow9 = nstart9 To 65536
        If CDate(Range("B" & nRow9).Value) = CDate("10/31/2017") Then
            nEnd9 = nRow9
            Exit For
        End If
    Next nRow9
    Range("F" & nstart9 & ":F" & nEnd9).Select
    'Dim r9 As Range
    'Set r9 = Selection
    'Intersect(r9(1).EntireRow, r9).Insert Shift:=xlDown, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

---

You can make it more dynamic by determining the used range in col B instead of hard-coding the last cell, and verifying the date against current month start / end